# What is the correct usage for 確認致しました上?

Tags: translation

I have written the below sentence to say that "due to feedback on A, fixes are required in B also, so we will do the required modifications'.

> Aのフィードバックを確認致しました上、それに応じてBにも修正する箇所が発生しましたので、当該修正に対応させて頂きます。

Is `確認致しました上` incorrect here?
I am trying to say "Upon checking X, we found that Y needs to be fixed as well'

Answer (score 2):

「V + 上」 has two major meanings. One is temporal order: "then" or "after". The other is "in addition".
Two events connected with 「上」 is rather independent of each other.

So your sentence would mean "I checked the feedback on A. In addition, I found ..."

Maybe this is not what you want.
You should say 「確認致しました**所**」.

「Vした + 所」 is basically translated as "when".
Its nuance is "I did V and what I got/found is ...", which matches this situation.

Comment: @Virmaior - Thank you. I was also implying here that based on what I found in A, there is correction required in B as well. Does 「確認致しました所」cover this as well?

Comment: @Ansh_RA Yes. 「Vした所」 has the nuance of something like "*due to doing V*" or "*as a result of doing V*". 　 Furthermore, you are using the good phrase 「それに応じて」. Using both 「～した所」 and 「それに応じて」, your intent would be very clear.